# how to compile dotnet project if you have more than one project or more than one .cs file in the same folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I use:

> dotnet run

Getting following error after running given command:

> Specify which project file to use because
>   /home/payal/Downloads/OPCUA-Azure-IoTHub-GW-master/SampleApplications/Samples/NetCoreConsoleClient
>   contains more than one project file.

Answer (score 5):

You can run specific project by adding `--project` to `dotnet run`.

Example: `dotnet run —project YourProjectName.csproj` (when executing the command in the same directory your project is, otherwise denote the full path of the location of the project)

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore21

Comment: **dotnet run --ProjectNetCoreConsoleClient.csproj**      
          Specify which project file to use because /home/payal/Downloads/OPCUA-Azure-IoTHub-GW-master/SampleApplications/Samples/NetCoreConsoleClient contains more than one project file.

Comment: No, you should be doing dotnet run —project YourProjectName.csproj Edited my answer with example

Comment: it is still giving the error. i have two files .csproj and .xproj i am using  dotnet run --project .csproj

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the correct full name of your project not just file exstension

Comment: Yes, it is working one required file was missing and i did dotnet restore first and the compiled the project. Thank you for the help